# Linear interpolation of continuous function error bound.

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation, numerical-calculus

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous,
and consider the linear interpolation

$$p(x)=\frac{b-x}{b-a}f(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b)$$
where $x\in [a,b]\subset{R}$. Suppose that $b-a=:h\downarrow 0$, is there a way to derive some error estimation in terms of Landau-$O$-notation such as
$$f(x)=p(x)+O(h^2)\qquad h\downarrow 0$$
since this is somehow suggested in a paper with that I have to work with. I don't see a clear way since there is no possibility to use error bounds via Taylor expansion.

Comment: By Newton interpolation $f(x)=f(a)+f[a,b](x-a)+f[a,b,x](x-a)(x-b)$ with $f[a,b,x]=\frac12f''(\xi)$ for some intermediate point.

Comment: The problem is that $f$ can not be assumed to be differentiable.

Comment: Then you do not get such an error bound. The best you get from continuity is $o(1)$ at both nodes, that is, relative to $(x-a)(x-b)$. Continuous functions can be very fractal, the nice continuous functions, that is Lipschitz or better, are a very thin subset.